# How to manage custom settings for a IIS6 hosted WCF service?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis

I have an wcf service that is hosted in II6. The service uses the server's file system to persist information. Now the persistence directory is hard coded to be F:\PM.
How can I use a configuration file to store this directory?  How can I access this file with a form application so as to modify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would place the information in the web.config file

```
   <appSettings>
    <add key="Directory" value="F:\PM" />
   </appSettings>
```

To read the value out of the config file

```
string directoryLocation = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Directory"];
```

To update the file from a winforms app, you could read and update the file.